# Finding all the occurrences of a pattern in a string using a SQL SERVER QUERY

Tags: sql-server

I want to filter all the occurrences of a pattern in a string using SQL server query. Ex: "#Hello world! Need to #filter the #tag" In this string need to filter the hashtag words...
The result should be...
"#Hello"
"#filter"
"#tag"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Would you expect to see #tag in the string `'the#tag'`? Why have you tagged SSIS? Are you wanting to do the process in that? If so, using what language?

Answer (score 0):

With the information displayed on the question, you could be referring to something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE column_A LIKE '#%'
```

This query will give you all fields in column column_A from table table_A with the hashtag symbol

Answer (score 0):

Using a string splitter this is pretty simple. I am using Jeff Moden's splitter which you can find [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

```
declare @asdf varchar(100) = '#Hello world! Need to #filter the #tag'

select *
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@asdf, ' ')
where Item like '#%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But unfortunately we are using SQL Server 2012 version which doesn't support "String_Split" function. Is there any other way?

Comment: You should read my answer again. This is NOT using the built in STRING_SPLIT. It is a different function entirely which absolutely will work on your version of sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if this works for you:

```
declare @tempTable table (hashtag varchar(Max))
declare @asdf varchar(100) = '#Hello world! Need to #filter the #tag'
declare @i integer =0
declare @length integer = (select len(@asdf)-len(replace(@asdf,'#','')))

while (select @i)< @length
begin
    insert into @tempTable select substring(@asdf,charindex('#', @asdf),charindex(' ', @asdf))
    set @asdf = ltrim((select substring(substring(@asdf,charindex('#', @asdf),len(@asdf)),charindex(' ', @asdf)+1,len(@asdf))))
    set @i = @i+1
end

select HashTag from @tempTable
```

Comment: Looping is not a great approach here. If they need to do this on an entire table they would be forced to use a loop for each row and then this loop on each row.

Comment: From the original question, there is no mention on "each rows" and/or other data set presented... so I was directly answering what was being asked which I understood as: "I have a string of x, and I need to split on # and return full words after #". If the requirement is different, then the OP should have asked differently.

Comment: Even so...looping should be avoided pretty much all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If Sean Lange is right and looping should be avoided, here's another answer that would work without looping:

```
declare @asdf varchar(100) = '#Hello world! Need to #filter the #tag'

SELECT 
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS HashTag
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<Records><Row>' + REPLACE(@asdf,' ','</Row><Row>') + '</Row></Records>' AS XML) AS x
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/Records/Row')m(n)
where LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)')))  like '#%'
```

You could then incorporate the above logic on a standard SELECT statement that could be applied on each row.